# Hibernate cancelQuery and query logging

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

I'm trying to implement query timeout functionality with Hibernate 3.3.2 and so far have been unsuccessful going the backend code approach.  Instead I've implemented a frontend solution to have a loading popup that uses javascript setTimeout function to call a servlet which invokes the Hibernate Session's cancelQuery method.

I have access to the Hibernate Session object and I want to log the query that's being cancelled.  Is this possible to do?

Note: We do have hibernate logging enabled, but we want a separate entry with the specifics of cancelled queries.